# Can I increase the index of map() by 2?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I have a problem with converting the array to object.

```
const data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr = data.map((element, idx) => {
  return {
    f: element,
    s: arr[idx + 1],
  };
});
```

Of course, `arr` is `[{f: 0, s: 1}, {f: 1, s: 2}, ...]`, but I want to increase the index of `map` by 2. The result will like this:

```
arr = [{ f: 0, s: 1}, { f: 2, s: 3 }, ...]
```

Is there any way to make the result using method likes `map`?

Comment: I think you'll have to use another loop (forEach, or traditional for loop) and keep track of a secondary index yourself

Comment: Maybe use reduce instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with **[`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** if I understood your question correctly:

```js
const data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const result = data.reduce((r,c,i,a) => {
  if(i%2 == 0)
    r.push({ f: i, s: a[i+1] })
  return r
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

The idea is to use the `%` operator in combination with the `reduce` to push only the values you would want into the `accumulator` array.

Doing this with map would be trickier since `map` goes through `every` element and expects the same number of elements out as they ware in where the `reduce` can have any result type/length specified by the `accumulator`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do pretty much anything with `reduce`, but it’s a bad fit for this:

```
arr = data.reduce( ( acc, item, i ) => {
    if ( i % 2 === 0 ) {
        acc[ acc.length - 1 ].s = item
    } else {
        acc.push({ f: item })
    }
    return acc
}, [] )
```

Better to split the array with a good old for loop, then map that:

```
var pairwise = arr => {
    var pairs = []
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        pairs.push([ arr[ i ], arr[ i + 1 ] ])
    }
    return pairs
}

arr = pairwise( data ).map( ([ f, s ]) => ({ f, s }) )
```